WKWebView accessibility tree not updated after DOM change
I have a simple UIKit app that pushes a view containing a WKWebView. If VoiceOver is enabled, when the view is pushed the OS sets the accessibility focus in the back button of the navigation bar. The problem is that when this occurs, the webview is not rendered (it shows an ampty view) so I suppose the accessibility tree is created and it only contains the back button. After a while, the web DOM changes (via JavaScript) showing web content in the webview, but when trying to move the focus by swipping right, the focus doesn't moves, it remains "stuck" into the back button (I suppose that it's because it doesn't know more elements in the accessibility tree)
It seems that when webview DOM is changed WKWebView doesn't update the accessibility tree.
Is there any way to enable that a DOM change forces OS to recreate the accessibility tree?
